# Set management port to be server port +1 in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-el, spring-boot-actuator

As my service can get port number injected through env variable `SERVER_PORT` I wanted management port to be +1 of this value. So I tried to configure it in `application.yml` using various combinations of idea below:

```
management.port: "#{ ${server.port:8080} + 1}"
```

resulting in: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{8080+1}"`

or

```
management.port: "# ${server.port:8080} + 1"
```

resulting in: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8080+1"`

How can I do this correctly? I have found in [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-vs-value) that SpEL is not working in application property files:

> Finally, while you can write a SpEL expression in @Value, such
>   expressions are not processed from Application property files.

But maybe there is some other way?

Comment: why dont change by api instead of application.yml?

Comment: I haven't thought about this. But this means that I will duplicate Spring's logic if I would like to have option to override it etc. Also this will be yet one another place where default properties are set :/